# Render parent element over x items in n array in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple map function:

```
<div>
    {
        items.map((item, index)=>(
            <p key={index}>{item}</p>
        ))
    }
</div>
```

Which renders this HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
</div>
```

How can I insert a span over the first 2 elements so that I have?

```
<div>
    <span>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
    </span>
    <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Ive tried:

```
<div>
    {
        items.map((item, index)=>(
            <>
                { index === 0 && <span> }
                <p key={index}>{item}</p>
                { index === items.length - 1 && </span> }
            </>
        ))
    }
</div>
```

But I get an error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to this expressions:

```
// You must render children if you don't close JSX tag <span></span>
{ index === 0 && <span> }

// Same here, <span/>
{ index === items.length - 1 && </span> }
```

> See [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Also, you trying to group two items under single span, doing it with a single map iteration may be over complicating things.

```
const items = [1, 2, 3];
const mapToParagraph = (item, index) => <p key={index}>{item}</p>;

const App = () => {
  // or slice for more generics
  const [first, second, ...rest] = items;
  return (
    <div>
      <span style={{ color: `red` }}>
        {[first, second].map(mapToParagraph)}
      </span>
      {rest.map(mapToParagraph)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit prod-tdd-m7qft]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add slash at the end for span.

```
                   <div>
                      {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((item, index) => (
                        <>
                          {index === 0 && <span />}
                          <p key={index}>{item}</p>
                          {index === [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].length - 1 && <span />}
                        </>
                      ))}
                    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

EDITED

```
<div>
    { 
        items.slice(0, 2).length > 0 && (
            <span>
                { items.slice(0, 2).map((it, i) => (
                    <p key={i}>{it}</p>
                ))}
            </span>
        )
    }
    {
        items.slice(2).map((it, i) => (
            p>{it}</p>
        ))
    }
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't group items, you wrap the first two items with `<span>`